# What does"is back" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

A. Schulzke's main claim is that actions in a virtual world are very different from actions in the real world, though a player may “kill” another player in a virtual world, that player **is** instantly **back** in the game and the two will almost certainly remain friends in the real world thus virtual violence is very different from real violence, a distinction gamers are comfortable with...

B. They **are back.**

C. They **will be back**.

I am confused with the bold parts. I mean what are the functions of the words"back" there? what kind of part of speech? And, what do really mean those three bold parts?

Meanwhile, what about b, and c?

Thanks

[enter link description here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/it-moral-values/)

Comment: "[To be back](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Back)" (adv. 2) simply means "to have returned to a former/original place/position". So in the case of a gamer: their character dies and then they are back means that the character returns to life (in the game).

Answer (score 1):

*'Back'* means *'to return'*. As simple as that. Now with the first sentence, *'back'* is used in its present tense, when the subject is singular.

> He **is back**

The second sentence refers to the present tense of *'back'*, when the number of subjects exceeds unity. That is a plural subject.

> The players **are back**.

As thirds sentence talks about a *'return'* in the near future. It has not happened yet, but soon will.

> They **will be back** tomorrow.

Its that simple. Its all about the time line - The past, the present and the Future.